# Require c# Normalising Math Formula based on attached array which generates bar chart % value output?

Tags: c#, arrays, percentage, algebra

## **Problem:**

So I am looking to create bar chart values based on a comparison to an array of values.

**Data:**
array = [25 , 35 , 55 , 5 , 60 , 200 , 18 , 18 , 30 , 10]

## **Requirements:**

I have a working Bar graph creation using CSS which loads the bar width value 'xx' as a percentage.

I want to allocate the lowest array item value to a percentage value of 100% (full width of CSS bar)  The above example would be the fourth array item '5'
Likewise the sixth item in the array is the highest number and I want to allocate 0% to the highest. 
*(Think of the numbers in the array as time - shortest being the best)*

So lowest (fourth) array item '5' = bar width value 100% and the

Highest array item '200' = bar width value 0%

The **spread between** the highest and lowest values in the array is 195

There are **10x items** in the array.

The **average value** across the array is **45.6**  which would for example generate a bar chart value of 50% if represented in the bar chart.

I am struggling to create a formula which dynamically generates the reverse percentage values from the varied array values above into a representational percentage bar chart value of any of the items in the array.

## **Specific Help Needed:**

Can you see the solution in C# so that I can generate percentage bar values based on the requirements outlined above ?

## **[EDIT] (Including my code which partly works)**

```
int[] array = { 25 , 35 , 55 , 5 , 60 , 200 , 18 , 18 , 30 , 10 };
int selectdVal = 5;  //example selection from array

int ratioSpread = 100; //used as 100% CSS width
int responseSlow = array.Max();  //The slowest val within array

decimal ratioAdjust = (ratioSpread / responseSlow);
decimal maxBar = 100 - (selectdVal * ratioAdjust );
int renderBar = Convert.ToInt16(maxBar <= 0 ? 1 : maxBar ); //show min 1% bar width
```

The above is relatively ok, but I'd prefer to have the shortest time (Min.value) of 5 above actually return 100 for the renderBar, whereas in this example it returns 97.5

Comment: The proper term for this is "normalizing" a set of data.

Comment: On hold for being too broad ? Its pretty specific in request of help.

Comment: You're asking us to just do the whole thing for you.  That is too broad of a question.  On this site it's expect that you'll have made some attempts to solve the problem yourself, shown what problems you have had with those attempts, etc. so that we can help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] array = { 25, 35, 55, 5, 60, 200, 18, 18, 30, 10 };
int selectdVal = 5;

int barMin = 1;
int barMax = 100;

decimal rangeMin = array.Min();
decimal rangeMax = array.Max();

decimal ratio = (barMax - barMin) / (rangeMax - rangeMin);

int bar = barMax - (int)(ratio * (selectdVal - rangeMin));
```

Comment: That's perfect !  Thank you so much.  I totally see where I was going wrong from your clear example :)